# TypeError: this.props.AddToList is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I want to pass the 'data' variable to App.js, I am exporting AddTodo component with the property 'AddToList' which calls the function Addnew , which then appends my list with the 'data' variable.
But when i click on the the button which class this.props.AddtoList , it throws this error. Please help.

Following is the code

```
//this is the button click handler
AddUserHandler = (e) => {
    let data = JSON.stringify(this.state);

    this.props.AddToList(data);
  };

//this is the props area in App.js , Addtodo is the exported class

<AddTodo AddTolist={this.AddNew} />

//this is the list appending function
AddNew = (data) => {
    const newTodo = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: data,
      completed: false,
    };
    this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo] });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, you're calling `this.props.AddToList` but in you're passing a prop with a lowercase "l"

```
<AddTodo AddTolist={this.AddNew} />
```

You can either fix the way you're accessing the prop to

```
this.props.AddTolist()
```

or you can fix what you're passing to the component to match what you're trying to access

```
<AddTodo AddToList={this.AddNew} />
```